# How do I filter a certain frequency using MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, fft

I have done a fourier transform of some experimental data to calculate the dominant frequency of the vibration in a flow, but I get a spike at 1000, which is from interferences. How do I ignore or filter this frequency to get the right frequency distribution?

Comment: you can take a look at the answers to a [previous question on hi-pass filtering](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5591278/high-pass-filtering-in-matlab). There is a lot of detail in them and you can simply change your pass-band from high pass to low pass to get the desired effect.

Comment: I would suggest designing a notch filter if you only need to remove a single frequency component

Answer (score 0):

The easiest approach is probably to use the Matlab function `iirnotch`.

```
x = ; % Populate this with your input signal

fsHz = ; % Populate this with your sample rate
notchFreqHz = 1000; % The frequency you with to notch
notchWidthHz = 50; % Notch width (-3 dB bandwidth)

w0 = notchFreqHz / fsHz; % Normalized notch frequency
bw = notchWidthHz / fsHz; % Normalized bandwidth

[num,den] = iirnotch(w0, bw);

y = filter(num, den, x); % Apply the filter, y is the output signal
```

See [Second-order IIR notch filter - MATLAB iirnotch](https://www.mathworks.com/help/dsp/ref/iirnotch.html) for more details.