# How can I apply a filter (high-pass) to a wav file in matlab

Tags: matlab, wav, highpass-filter

I have a few second length sound clip (.wav) and need to apply a high-pass filter to see the high frequency components of that.

```
AI=analoginput('winsound'); 
addchannel(AI,1);
set(AI, 'SampleRate', 8000);
set(AI, 'SamplesPerTrigger', 32000);
start(AI);
data=getdata(AI);
wavwrite(data,'audio.wav');
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add all necessary details: how did you call `fmdemod`. What are your parameters of your input wav file?

Comment: Thank you for adding the code! Another thing you could add to your question is why `fmdemod` didn't help you - did you get wrong results? Is there an error message? I'm no matlab expert, but I think the more information you give, the easier it is to find an answer..

Comment: My question was taken its final format

Comment: or [High-pass filtering in MATLAB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5591278/high-pass-filtering-in-matlab), or any of the dozens of other questions here.